# Connectivity Issues in Minecraft - Desyncing Often and Constant Spikes

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On any server I play on I am constantly experiencing lag related issues such as:

- Desyncing from server (server world not in sync with player)
- Lag related spikes every minute at least (spikes can last from 1 second all the way to 15)

I have had no problems on my previous laptop I used to play Minecraft on, and my brother can be on the exact server using the exact same internet and does not have these issues. This has been an issue ever since I built a new gaming computer. Currently I'm using an old USB wireless adapter to allow me to connect via WIFI to my internet. I'm not even sure if this device is to blame, though it could be.

I performed 100 ping requests to Google.ca to see if I had any packet loss, and there was none. I also did a speed test and it reported the usual speed I'd get from other computers on my network.

I don't have any of these issues in any other games, so I'm really confused at howto go about trouble shooting this issue, and how I should resolve it. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: I just tested doing 1000 pings to google.ca instead of only 100 like I did before and here are the results:

```
Ping statistics for 173.194.43.87:
    Packets: Sent = 1000, Received = 967, Lost = 33 (3% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 10ms, Maximum = 328ms, Average = 15ms
```

Comment: Are you running any mods?

Comment: @pattyd Yes, but these are mods that I can use with no issue on my laptop, and I've tested without them.

Comment: Could you be running anything on that computer (or any other computer on your network, for that matter) that might be causing network usage to spike about once a minute for the duration of the lag? If your bandwidth is being swallowed up by something else every now and again, it could cause problems.

Comment: The most likely culprit here seems to be Java. Take a look and see if that's updated so that we can rule it out.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to your brother's server through a network switch? If there are *still* problems with that kind of direct connection then your computer is the problem. Otherwise it's likely your USB stick, which I've had terrible results with in the past.

Comment: Try connecting to a different server, the problem could be with the server. Also, try allocating more RAM to Minecraft, or installing optifine and configuring the settings it comes with appropriatly. Also, just *HOW* old is your video card?

Comment: @avestar101 I don't think you even read the first sentence of my question. I specifically mentioned that this happens across ANY server I join.

Comment: @SadlyNot Did you read my question? My brother doesn't even have a server. I have issues with any server you could find of a server list.

Comment: @Coronus I have the latest version of Java (Version 7 Update 25). I just built this computer and set everything up, so any software updates should not be an issue, as it is all fresh from the makers sites.

Comment: Those ping results look like the problem. An average of 15ms, min of 10ms, max of **328ms**? Min and average close together and a 30x higher max suggests you get spikes normally. Since Minecraft doesn't have the best networking design, that's probably why it suffers but other games don't.

Comment: @Fogest facepalm, I missed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "ever since I built my new gaming computer" is cluing me to issues with your wifi adapter. Old adapters don't particularly have (good) drivers that work well in newer versions of Windows.

Depending on the game you play, you could potentially experience the same issue as well. Minecraft is *very* sensitive to latency. Other games compensate by things like motion prediction and other things. Minecraft is just Java + UDP ...that's it.

A test would be to `ping /t minecraft.server.ip` and connect to the server and attempt to play. If you see drops/spikes, then it's your adapter not able to keep up. However, it's also possible that pinging won't do much since it's a different protocol.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is it. The almost 1/3 second ping time when the average is 15ms and min is 10ms says "spike" to me, and that would kill Minecraft's networking.

Comment: Okay, I think you are right that this is probably caused by my adapter. I know others have said the same, but they have failed to mention why other games are working fine, and expand on why Minecraft is the only game I face this issue in, so it was crucial that you mentioned why. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Wanted to make this a comment... Not sure how. But in terms of trouble shooting, see if you can't connect the laptop to your wi-fi via the old USB mah'jig. Then try the server, now using the verified laptop, but the suspected USB wi-fi...

That would be my next step in terms of trouble shooting. (That or Ethernet cable right into the new pc then retry. You could set up the machine near the router or modem temporarily to try it out at least. It would seem, anyhow.)

Seems like you did all the other groundwork though. Sounds like it is some tiny subtle issue with that card.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your computer is laggy, or the server you are playing on is laggy.
What you can try:

- Close all open programs besides minecraft when playing
- Upgrade your internet to a faster speed
- Get an upgraded modem/router
- If you are playing wirelessly (wirelessly connected to the internet) Try connecting a cable from you computer to your router
- Upgrade your computer processor/graphics card
- If it is lag from the server, and not your computer, try to contact the server admin and let them know.

There are many more solutions on Google, so if none of my solutions work, then try looking there.

Comment: Did you read my question? This is not a FPS issue at all, I just put together this gaming computer and it can easily surpass 200 FPS. This is related to connection, not FPS. My internet is a fine speed. As my question states it works fine from other computers using wireless and the same network. I would need a cable to go through two levels to get to the router. Computer upgrade not needed. It is not the server as I've stated.

Comment: @Fogest, I never said anything about FPS... I said that you might be getting lag. There are other kinds of lag that don't have anything to do with FPS. What you just explained tells me that you either have a laggy connection or computer, or that the server is lagging. Maybe you graphics card can't handle minecraft for some reason, or some hardware is malfunctioning/needs an update. The possibilities are just about endless. Try looking at this issue from every possible angle, and you will probably find the solution. If I can be any more help to you, please let me know!

Comment: It is not my graphics card. This is connection related, for sure. I  think it is possibly my usb network adapter.

Comment: Like i had said: Upgrade your internet! :) I hope that some of what I posted helped you! Try to hard-wire your computer to your router, you can get really long cabels at WalMart :)

Comment: I think I'm just going to get a wireless adapter and put it in one of my expansion slots.

Comment: Cool, +1 on your question because it is interesting! I hope that my answer helped at least a little bit :)

Comment: Yeah, it is an interesting question. It is weird because I can play  other games with a fine ping and no connection issues.

Answer (score 0):

**Is it a problem with the server?**
You should first verify that this is not something on the server causing the problem.

- Make sure there isn't anyone setting off TNT or dropping a lot of stuff on the ground.
- Make a new world on the server and see if it lags then. If so, it's a problem with the map, not your computer.

**Is it a problem with your computer?**

- Get OptiFine and turn off most animations and set it to MaxFPS. Explore all the options and turn all of the unneeded ones off.
- If your computer is plugged in, change the battery usage to "High Performance".
- Exit all other programs.
- Allocate more RAM to Minecraft.
- Windows Update

  - Update *ALL* the drivers!
  - Manually update if Windows is being stupid.
- Try disabling your firewall and antivirus.

  - Perhaps your computer has a virus. Have you scanned it?

**Is it a problem with your Internet?**

- If you use a wireless connection, try a wired one.
- See if the router antennae is loose or starting to come off the router.
- Consider getting a faster Internet plan or a better router.

  - [Check your Internet connection speed first](http://www.speedtest.net/).

Also remember that Minecraft is different than other games because it is coded in Java, and is responsible for memory leaks and stuff.

Comment: Did you read my original post? It is not a server owned by me, and I've tried it on multiple servers, and I get the same kind of issues. Play on it fine with my laptop. This is not any FPS issue, my computer is fine with every other game and gets 100+ FPS on max settings in Minecraft.

Comment: -1 for answering a problem that the asker doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your your network connection performance? You can try to check it here -> http://www.netscan.co/

There is The Connectivity Checker will perform a series of network tests for modern Web Services like WebSockets and WebRTC. A unique url will be created with the results which you can then share with an expert to get your problem diagnosed.

It was helpful for me, I hope that it will be as helpful for you too.